# How to iterate in loop using subprocess.call in python

Tags: python, shell

Im trying to iterate in loop after the subprocess call but getting the error

> 

```
from subprocess import PIPE, call
cmd1 = 'find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name *.xml -type f -mtime +1'
result = call(cmd1,shell=True)
resultlist = result.split('/n')
for fname in resultlist:
    print(FileName - ':fname)
```

resultlist = result.split('/n')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: `subprocess.call()` is not appropriate if you want the actual output from the command - all it gives you is the exit code.  Try `.run()` or `.check_output()` instead.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I'm using python 2.7 in the server it doesn't support run(). Pls give me some sample for check_output() as I'm new to Python